# Dirichlet Characters, Characteristic Functions, and Orthogonality in Proof of Dirichlet's Theorem

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, dirichlet-character

I am confused by the justification of Equation 7 from [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_14/papers/austin.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_14/papers/austin.pdf), which states that (substituting in the definitions and slightly modifying the notation)

$$\sum_{\substack{p\text{ prime}\\p\equiv a\pmod{N}}} \frac{1}{p^s} = \sum_{\chi}\left(\frac{\overline{\chi}(a)}{\phi(N)}\sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}\right)$$

where the second sum is over all Dirichlet characters modulo $N$, and the notation $\overline{\chi}(a)$ denotes the inverse of $\chi$ in the group of Dirichlet characters.

According to the source, this follows from the fact that $P_a(s) = P_a(s)\Phi_a(n)$ where

$$\Phi_a(n) = \begin{cases}1,&\text{if }n\equiv a\pmod N\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and

$$P_a(s) = \sum_{\substack{p\text{ prime}\\p\equiv a\pmod{N}}} \frac{1}{p^s}$$

and the orthogonality relations of the Dirichlet characters. But the right-hand side of Equation 7 (the first equation I listed) depends only on $s$, not on $n$, but $P_a(s)\Phi_a(n)$ depends on $a$ and $n$, so how are they equal.

Perhaps this isn't the best way to phrase my question. I could also rephrase my questions as follows:

**Can someone please give a full, step-by-step derivation for Equation 7 that provides more details than the proof given in Tran's work?**

Comment: But the RHS does depend on $n$? It has $\phi(n)$ in it and the sum is over the characters mod $n$ no?

Comment: You are right that equation (7) doesn't really make sense as written. I imagine what is meant is $$P_a(s) = \sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p^s} \Phi_a(p) = \sum_{\chi}\left(\frac{\overline{\chi}(a)}{\phi(N)}\sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}\right).$$

Comment: @runway44: $n$ and $N$ are different

Comment: @GregMartin, Your sum makes more sense to me. I suspect that you are correct that this is the intended sum. But if we apply the orthogonality relationship with $\Phi_a$ , then we $\sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p^s}\Phi_a(p) = \sum_{p\text{ prime}} \sum_{\chi} \frac{\overline{\chi}(a)}{\phi(n)} \chi(n)$, but the correct formula has the sums reversed (that is, the outermost sum depends on $\chi$ and the innermost sum on $p$, unlike the sum here). Can you explain the justification for reversing the order of the sums?